# Not able to iterate map to print multiple rows

Tags: jsp, tags

I am trying to print rows (around 50 fields) based on the number of check boxes selected. If two rows are selected, then in the next page I have to print all the 50 values of each row.

I am able to print successfully if it is just one row.
But not able to do the same for multiple rows.

I have my controller class code like this :

```
RequestMapping(value = { "dispo/searchDisplay.do" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String selectForm(ModelMap model,
            @RequestParam("cid") int warrantsId) {

        az.dps.adrs.web.domain.HwrsWarrants hwrsWarrants = hwrsWarrantsService.setLookupValues(hwrsWarrantsService.find(warrantsId), getAuthentication());
        HwrsWarrantsResult searchResults  = hwrsWarrantsService.select(hwrsWarrants,TRANSACTION_TYPE_HWRS_WARRANTS_DISPLAY,getAuthentication());
        Map<String, Object> results = searchResults.getSearches();
        model.addAttribute("hwrsWarrants", hwrsWarrants);
        model.addAttribute("resultSet", results);
        model.addAttribute("results", hwrsWarrantsService.find(warrantsId));
        model.addAttribute("transactionType", TRANSACTION_TYPE_HWRS_WARRANTS_DISPLAY);
        return "searchDisplay";
}

@RequestMapping(value = { "dispo/searchDisplay.do" }, method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String selectForm(ModelMap model,
            @ModelAttribute("hwrsWarrants") HwrsWarrants hwrsWarrants) {
    HwrsWarrantsResult searchResults  = hwrsWarrantsService.select(hwrsWarrants,TRANSACTION_TYPE_HWRS_WARRANTS_DISPLAY,getAuthentication());
    Map<String, Object> results = searchResults.getSearches();
    RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes().setAttribute("results", results, RequestAttributes.SCOPE_SESSION);
    RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes().setAttribute("hwrsWarrants", hwrsWarrants, RequestAttributes.SCOPE_SESSION);
    model.addAttribute("results", results);     
    model.addAttribute("hwrsWarrants",hwrsWarrants);
    model.addAttribute("transactionType", TRANSACTION_TYPE_HWRS_WARRANTS_DISPLAY);
    if (searchResults.isTooManyRows())
        model.addAttribute("errorMessages", getTooManyRowsWarning(searchResults.getMaxRows()));
    return "searchDisplay";
}
```

In my jsp, I am trying to iterate like this:

```
<c:forEach items="${results}" var="results">
<table width="100%" cellspacing="0" class="RecSrcAll" cellpadding="2" border="0">
```

Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: jsp code :  <c:forEach items="${results}" var="results">
            <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" class="RecSrcAll" cellpadding="2" border="0">
              <tr>

Comment: What exactly happens when you try to print multiple rows?  What does the rest of your `<c:forEach>` block look like?

Comment: Also, using the same variable name for the list of results (`items="${results}"`) and for the current result (`var="results"`) is not really a good idea. You wouldn't write `for (results : results)`, would you?

Comment: Yeah. Actually I have realized my prob is with the multiple select of checkbox. It is not working. I am able to print only one row value rather than multiple rows, though I selected multple rows thru checkbox.